# How to change color of the points and remove the joined line in the given code?

Tags: plotting, mesh

I use this code

```
{data1, data2} = Transpose[Table[{2 n, 3 n + 100}, {n, 20}]];
a = ListPlot[{data1, data2}, Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[Scaled[10^-2]]], 
    Directive[Blue, Thickness[Scaled[10^-2]]]}, Mesh -> All, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red],
  ClippingStyle -> False]
```

and I get this picture

[image]

Now, I have two questions:

1. How can I ask Mathematica to change the color (red to blue) and shape (circle to diamond) of the plotmarker in the upper curve?
2. How can I remove the joined line for the upper curve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListPlot[{data1, data2}, 
 Joined -> {True, False}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[Scaled[10^-2]]], Blue},
 PlotMarkers -> {{"●", 12}, {"◆", 12}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
{data1, data2} = Transpose[Table[{2 n, 3 n + 100}, {n, 20}]];
a = ListPlot[data1, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[Scaled[10^-2]]], 
     Directive[Blue, Thickness[Scaled[10^-2]]]}, Mesh -> All, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
   ClippingStyle -> False];
b = ListPlot[data2, Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Blend[{Red, Blue}, x]]];
Show[a, b, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wanted the upper points to only be pure blue and change their shape to diamond.

Comment: @charmin Sorry, I misunderstanding " red to blue"

Comment: Thanks, it was my bad in writing.